# AndEngine game show black screen before loading

Tags: android, andengine

I have developed the Game in AndEngine but it shows black screen for some time before loading.I have so many research but till now I did not found proper answers to remove black screen.Please help me how to resolve this.

it is very difficult for me. please take seriously and help me

Comment: In order us to take seriously your question, please edit your question and share the code with us!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The black screen appears after the app is started and stays there until the required graphics resources for the game are loaded into memory. If the black screen annoys you, there are two options I know of:

1. You can try to make your loading sequence shorter by making your
   code as efficient as possible. You can look at tips for this
   [here](http://www.matim-dev.com/tips-and-tricks---how-to-improve-performance.html).
2. Another possibility is to have what is called a [splash
   screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splash_screen). See [this tutorial](http://www.matim-dev.com/splash-screen---easy-way.html) for how to this in AndEngine.